# unable to execute shell_exec() with variable

Tags: php, shell, server, shell-exec

I'm trying to run shell_exec() with variable passed with AJAX from client.

This code causes error (input file doesn't exist!):

```
$searched_image = escapeshellarg("/home/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/sp_dom1.jpg");
$old_path = getcwd();
chdir('../elevation/source_code/altitudes_system/');
$altitudes_system_result = shell_exec('./predict_altitude.sh -i "{$searched_image}" -p basic -o 0');
chdir($old_path);
```

But when I replace "{$searched_image}" in shell_exec(...) with /home/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/sp_dom1.jpg code works well:

```
$old_path = getcwd();
chdir('../elevation/source_code/altitudes_system/');
$altitudes_system_result = shell_exec('./predict_altitude.sh -i /home/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/sp_dom1.jpg -p basic -o 0');
chdir($old_path);
```

Don't you have any idea why it works like this?

Comment: Get rid of the double quotes around `{$searched_image}`, as `escapeshellarg()` is likely already adding single quotes for you.  Build a string and feed that to `shell_exec()` so you can echo your command line and see what it actually is.

Comment: Still doesnt work when I remove double quotes. And when I build the string - $searched_image = escapeshellarg('./predict_altitude.sh -i /home/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/XXX/sp_dom1.jpg -p basic -o 0'); like this, it outputs exactly what I want to have in my command line - './predict_altitude.sh -i ....' and then when I call shell_exec($searched_image); it doesn't output result but it doesn't event output error..

Comment: In your example in your comment, you're using `escapeshellarg()` incorrectly.  You use it to escape ***a single argument***, not a whole command line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write:

```
'./predict_altitude.sh -i "{$searched_image}" -p basic -o 0'
```

Inside single-quoted strings variables are not evaluated.

You can use this, instead:

```
"./predict_altitude.sh -i '{$searched_image}' -p basic -o 0"
```

Or - to avoid unpredictable evaluations - this:

```
$cmd = './predict_altitude.sh -i \''.$searched_image.'\' -p basic -o 0';
shell_exec( $cmd );
```